# Is it possible to skin a movie player in iOS 5?

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiappearance

I know that `UIAppearance` has been introduced in iOS 5, but is there any way of using the new protocol to reskin the `MPMoviePlayerController`, or do I still need to get my hands dirty using `drawRect` methods and the like?

Does anyone have any good examples of reskinned movie players for the iPad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MPMoviePlayerController`'s user interface is entirely transparent for you as a developer. You can not change its appearance at all. You can only replace the UI by hiding the default interface and showing your own as explained in detail within the following SO answers:

[To what extent can the iOS Movie Player be customized and styled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445291/to-what-extent-can-the-ios-movie-player-be-customized-and-styled)

[Adding custom controls to a full screen movie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422807/adding-custom-controls-to-a-full-screen-movie)

*One additional note though:
Even though this does enable you to create a customized movie player, Apple clearly recommends  against doing that - and once again for good reason. The player, as is, does provide a well functioning, good looking and accustomed UI to the end user. Customizing the interface, in almost all attempts, will reduce the usability. Trust me, I have done it numerous times for various customers that insisted in having their branded player - yet I have never encountered a design that feels as good as the one Apple provides you with.*

Comment: @rickster oops, those went awall when posting - sry. Fixed now.

Comment: Many thanks for the info and links. I agree that customising the controls is generally not a good idea, however it is a potential requirement for our particular client's branding, and it is for an internal point-of-sale Enterprise app thingy... So I'd just like to tell them whether it is possible or not.

Comment: One question, does this also work for fullscreen mode as well, or do I have to create my own fullscreen mode? I downloaded BBC iPlayer and it looks like they've created their own "fullscreen" mode...

Comment: Yes it does work for both, embedded and fullscreen playback - you may customize both. There are some pitfalls for fullscreen mode but those are not deal breakers, just issue one has to know :D ... to be asked and answered in other questions.